# Migration of svn+ssh to svnserve

Tags: svn, ssh

I have a Subversion repository with several active users presently configured only for svn+ssh use.  I would like to migrate the repository to use the svnserve protocol instead to make it more accessible to new users and secure.  Are there any things that I should be worried about if I start using svnserve on a repository also accessed by ssh?  Can I still use the same repository for ssh access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that there won't be any big issue using both access in parallel as long as files ownership and permissions are correctly set.

You could have a look at [this section of the SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.multimethod.html) to get some hints about what needs your attention.

Comment: Didn't see that section of the book hiding down there!